# How can I reduce Cyclomatic complexity?

Tags: java, cyclomatic-complexity

I have a method like below. Please help to avoid Cyclomatic complexity.

```
private double getSum(Data data) {
    double total = 0;

    if(parameters.getParam1())
      total += data.getParam1();

    if(parameters.getParam2())
      total += data.getParam2();

    if(parameters.getParam3())
      total += data.getParam3();

    if(parameters.getParam4())
      total += data.getParam4();

    if(parameters.getParam5())
      total += data.getParam6();

    if(parameters.getParam6())
      total += data.getParam6();

    if(parameters.getParam7())
      total += data.getParam7();

    if(parameters.getParam8())
      total += data.getParam8();

    return total;
}
```

Comment: That code won't compile, so there's nothing to reduce.

Comment: Sounds like a question for http://codereview.stackexchange.com. Please move it

Comment: The `if` statement indicates `getParamX` returns a boolean, but the if-body indicates the `+=` operator can be used - which isn't possible with a boolean. Please make it make sense.

Comment: @JeroenVannevel but in the if OP uses `parameters` then inside the if `data`

Comment: @ReneLink you could imagine that a warning is emitted by some analysis tool and the op wants to fix the code so SO is fine IMO.

Comment: @RenéLink: totally overlooked that, my bad.

Comment: Where is `parameters` defined?

Comment: Are the results of getParamX() not independant in some way?  Can you infer the value of getParamX_m() from getParamX_n()?

Comment: The check for param 5 adds param 6.

Comment: Here, Parameters class defines whether to use that parameter or not. If Parameters class return true the value of that parameter is taken from Data class. I have just changes the name of the parameter for security reasons.

Answer (score 1):

I would create a method like this:

```
double doubleOrZero(boolean condition, double value) {
    return condition ? value : 0.0;
}
```

Then call it for each *paramX*, like this:

```
private double getSum(Data data) {
    double total = 0.0;

    total += doubleOrZero(parameters.getParam1(), data.getParam1());
    total += doubleOrZero(parameters.getParam2(), data.getParam2());
    // ...
```

Comment: Or simply `return a ? b : 0:`

Answer (score 1):

As other mentioned, you will be better of to rewrite your `Parameter` and `Data` class, to uses them like this:

```
double total=0; 
for (int i=1; i<=8;i++)
    if (parameters.hasParam(i))
        total+ = data.getParam(i);
return total;
```

Answer (score 0):

For the given code sample, it is only possible the reduce boilderplate by using reflection, like this:

```
double total=0; 
for (int i=1; i<=8;i++)
    if (parameters.getClass().getMethod("getParam"+i).invoke(parameters)==Boolean.TRUE)
        total+ = (double)data.getClass().getMethod("getParam"+i).invoke(data);
return total;
```

Comment: I was working on a similar approach but without reflection. Reflect kills static type checking etc and IMHO probably makes the overall code quality worse then the original.

Comment: @MiserableVariable Yes thats indeed not best practice and unreadable too, but the only option i know to reduce boilerplate in this case.

Comment: It doesn't reduce cyclomatic complexity either as your trading 8 if statements for a for loop that counts to 8.  Parameterizing getMethod() with i increases the number of states exactly as much as reducing the number of states by eliminating the if statements.

Comment: How about just changing `getParam1()`, `getParam2()`, etc to `getParam(int i)`? Assuming the OP can actually do such a change.

Comment: @waTeim the cyclomatic complexity does not increase with each iteration, it is statically determined and for a loop it adds 1, just as for if statement.

Comment: ok, i interpreted it to mean +1 path per iteration if a branch was possible inside the loop.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a hint. Consider the following code:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
  if (paramGetters[i].get(parameters)) {
    total += paramGetters[i].get(data);
  }
}
```

**UPDATE1**

Some more hints how this can be made to compile:

`paramGetters` is an array of objects of some type that have an overloaded `get` method: `get(paramters)` returns a `boolean`, `get(data)` returns a `number`. Also, each object calls one of the specific `getParam` method.

**UPDATE2**

The following lines set the first element of the array:

```
paramGetters[0] = new ParamGetter() {
    boolean get(Parameters p) { return p.getGame(); }
    double get(Data d) { return d.getGameValue(); }
}
```

This is based on OP's comment about the actual methods to be called. I will leave it you to define the class, the array, and the rest of the elements in the array.

Comment: I am sorry Guys. I think i put the example incorrectly. For security reasons i changes the parameter names like param1, param2 etc. The parameter names are very different like game, hotel, etc.

Comment: Correct example:

private double getSum(Data data)
  {
    double total = 0;
    
    if(parameters.getGame())
      total += data.getGameValue();
    
    if(parameters.getHotel())
      total += data.gethotelValue();
    
    if(parameters.getBar())
      total += data.getBar Value();

    return total;
}

Comment: You can still do that with my example. I will add one more hint now